# How do I debug differences between development and production in a meteor app?

Tags: meteor

My meteor app fails to find both packages and template helpers when running in production that work just fine in development.  I have no idea where to start to debug this problem.  Are there any resources out there?  I've been googling for 2 hours with no luck.

What I've found so far:

- Meteor.startup() for global code that uses variables in other files (has no effect whatsoever on the crash)

That's it.  The problem's I'm specifically having are that nemo64:bootstrap is not recognized, so my ui-account-bootstrap package complains that there is no bootstrap package loaded, and some global template helpers registered with Template.registerHelper() don't exist when the templates are rendered.

Comment: I still don't have a clear sense of how to do this without fumbling about, but I did manage to find a problem that SHOULD have crashed in development but didn't (collection declared twice).  Once I fixed that, the site suddenly started working.  I suspect that the exception was crashing the whole site when it was combined into a single file, but didn't when files were separate

Comment: How about using the official Bootstrap package for Meteor? https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap

Comment: @FullStack nemo64 has its advantages. You can choose to only use certain parts of bootstrap with it